# Nodejs how to do some logic when previous logic were done

Tags: node.js, synchronous

An array`[1,2,3,4]`take 2 of them and send 2 requests with them;

Once completed take another 2 and create two new requests;

I know I cant do it like below because Nodejs is synchronous;

```
var request = require('request');
var args=[1,2,3,4];
function chunk(){...}
args = chunk(args,2);   //My custom function to split array into chunks

args.forEach(function(value)
{
    value.forEach(function(value_value)
    {
       /***********sent requests**************/
        var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://dev.site/date.php',
            formData: {arguments:value_value}
        };
        request(options, function (error, response, body)
        {
            if (body=='hello') {
                console.log(body);
            }
        });
      /**************************************/
    });
});
```

please Help me

Comment: If you're willing to use a third party module, I can recommend `lodash`'s `chunk`: http://devdocs.io/lodash~4/index#chunk
In order to make requests sequentially, rather than all at once, I recommend looking into a module like `async` with its `eachSeries` function: http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.eachSeries

Comment: thx for quick answer maybe Im not explain exactly,I mean I need to wait some logic done then step to the next

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request-promise` and `q` - then chain response:

```
var request = require('request-promise');
var Q = require('q');
var args=[1,2,3,4];

function chunk(){...}
args = chunk(args,2);   //My custom function to split array into chunks

args.forEach(function(value)
{
     var result = Q();
     args.forEach(function (t) {
        result = result.then(request_each.bind(null, value));
     });
     return result;  // result has the final promise (use .then on that)
});

function request_each(value) {
    return Q.all(value.forEach(function(value_value)
    {
       /***********sent requests**************/
        var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://dev.site/date.php',
            formData: {arguments:value_value}
        };

        return request(options);           
      /**************************************/
    }));
 }
```

You can just use `q` and `request` (changing the `request_each` function):

```
function request_each(value) {
    return Q.all(value.forEach(function(value_value)
    {
       var deferred = Q.defer();
       /***********sent requests**************/
        var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://dev.site/date.php',
            formData: {arguments:value_value}
        };

        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (body=='hello') {
                deferred.resolve(body);
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise;           
      /**************************************/
    }));
 }
```